# Using apply with a different function argument for each element's evaluation

Tags: r, apply

Let's say I have a matrix, mat.

```
mat <- matrix(1:5, nrow = 10, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

And I have some sort of function that I want to apply, in this case by column.

```
getRMSE <- function(true, est) {
    sqrt(mean((true - est)^2))
}
```

(This function is just the most recent example, but I've had this exact same conundrum at least 5 more times.)

If you want to apply a function over a matrix, you use apply.  But what if you want to apply   a function over a matrix with different values for 'x' in the apply?

In this case, the goal would be that apply would perform the equivalent of this:

```
getRMSE(mat[,1], 1)
getRMSE(mat[,2], 2)
getRMSE(mat[,3], 3)
```

But I always run into problems when giving a vector as a supplementary argument to the function. Obviously

```
apply(mat, 2, getRMSE, c(1,2,3))
```

isn't going to work, because it will recycle the numbers within the columns, too.  But

```
apply(mat, 2, getRMSE, rep(c(1,2,3), 25))
```

also doesn't work, which I thought at least had a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `mapply` where `x` would be your matrix column, and `y` the constant. I didn't bother with converting the matrix into a list the smart way, so I have to use `unlist` inside the function.

```
mat <- matrix(1:5, nrow = 10, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

mat.list <- apply(mat, MARGIN = 2, FUN = list)

mapply(FUN = function(x, y) {
  sqrt(mean((unlist(x) - y)^2))
}, x = mat.list, y = list(1, 2, 3))

[1] 2.449490 1.732051 1.414214
```

Comment: That's ... really interesting. I'm not even sure I understand what's going on there, but that's kind of par for the course with me and the applies. It definitely wouldn't make my code any cleaner, but maybe that's just the best I'm going to get here.

Comment: @Chib look at the examples in `mapply`. It applies the specified function to corresponding elements of lists. These list elements are passed along as function argument names. In other words, it takes first element of `x` and `y` and applies the function. It takes second elements of `x` and `y` and applies the function. And so on until the end of time or list.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, just roll the "est" values out to a matrix that matches the "true" values. Then you can subtract matrices (which R will automatically do componentwise) and use `apply()`, or here, `colMeans()`:

```
> true <- matrix(1:5, nrow = 10, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
> est <- matrix(1:3,nrow=nrow(true),ncol=ncol(true),byrow=TRUE)
> sqrt(colMeans((true-est)^2))
[1] 2.449490 1.732051 1.414214
>
```

In more general cases involving lists, `mapply()` may be helpful.

Comment: This is what I end up doing most of the time, but I feel like it makes my code less readable. My thought is that there is some obvious implementation of one of the 'apply' family of functions that would do what I wanted.  mapply() didn't sound right, but I guess I could look into it again.